# Separating a string by "\n" in monoTouch

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xamarin.ios

So I have a very big String that I want to separate on every line and put each line as object in a Array. In objective-c this would work by using:

```
NSArray *piecesArray = [tmpString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

However if I try this in monoTouch I get system.string[] as return value. Here is the code that I use in c#:

```
var defaults = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults;

            //Collecting Trace and Trace data from link + security code and converting Track and Trace data into string
            TracTraceDataString = NSString.FromData (NSData.FromUrl 
                                                    (NSUrl.FromString ("http://plex.janssen1877.com/app/life/" + defaults ["SecurityToken"])), 
                                                     NSStringEncoding.UTF8);

            //Seperating the string and putting each object in the array
            TrackTraceDataArray = TracTraceDataString.Split (new char[] { '\n' }, 2);


            Console.WriteLine (TrackTraceDataArray);
```

Comment: What do you expect it would return?

Comment: @JohnWillemse Well I'm new to c# but in objective-c this would return all objects in the array. With console.writeline I want to check the content of the array.

Comment: Ah okay, so the problem is in that line.. I thought you were surprised that it returned a `string[]`, my bad. You have to iterate over the array explicitly with a `for` or `foreach` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
Console.WriteLine (TrackTraceDataArray);
```

to:

```
foreach (string s in TrackTraceDataArray)
    Console.WriteLine (s);
```

Comment: It's unlikely the array has an overloaded ToString method so this is the best way to go about writing out the items

Comment: Thank you that was the problem. I thought there was something wrong with the split.